# Checking if input is correct type java

Tags: java, types, error-handling, throw

```
    System.out.println("What letter should the word begin with?");
        char letter = input.next().charAt(0);
        if(letter != ''){
            throw new InputMismatchException("Please input a letter");
        }
```

I want to check to see if the user input anything besides a string/char. If they have I want to throw an exception that says the input is wrong. This is my current code but as it stands it does not compile.

Comment: Everything the user can enter is a char. There's no way to enter anything other than chars. You need to tell us what **your** definition of char is. But, have you at least read the javadoc of java.lang.Character?

Comment: What is the overall goal of your program?

Comment: Every input can be interpreted as a char because every character, every number and every punctuation sign it's an ascii character. You must tell whats the goal of the program to can give you some advice as @TimBiegeleisen said.

Comment: @J.Lorenzo actually, most of them are not ASCII characters. ASCII only support 127 characters.

Comment: This program parses through the scrabble dictionary and picks out words that the user wants, hence why I ask the user the beginning letter of the word that they would like to find. However part of the assignment is also to "catch" the errors that could be inputted by the user. In this case, I could imagine the user not inserting a string and thus the entire dictionary would be searched for a word that starts with perhaps a number like 8, which will return a blank ArrayList.

Comment: So, you want the user to enter a **letter** between 'A' and 'Z'. That's not the same thing as a char. '1' is a char. 'é' is a char. '' is a char. So you want `if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z')`.

Comment: Yes, thats true @JBNizet. In the firsts java versions, char variable was supposed to use to map every option in the ascii table (7 of the 8 bits = 127 possibilities). Nowadays char variable is a 16 bit variable to can support Unicode charset that fits in every language. I just want to say that every input that you can give from the keyboard can be a char.

Comment: @J.Lorenzo Java has **always** used Unicode, and Java chars have always been two-bytes long.

Comment: I could not check the documentation but you are right @JBNizet, i was wrong (my C knowledgment gave me a bad point of view). That doesn't necessarily mean that every representation of a character is 2 bytes long. Many encodings only reserve 1 byte for every character (or use 1 byte for the most common characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether `letter` is a letter like this:

```
if ((letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') || (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z'))
```

Actually, `Scanner` has this handy overload of `next(String pattern)` that throws an `InputMismatchException` automatically if the input does not match a pattern:

```
char letter = input.next("[a-zA-Z]").charAt(0);
```

`[a-zA-Z]` is the [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) used here. It accepts any character from a to z or from A to Z.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have fixed the issue!